# Problems passing a file to another Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, send

Extremely weird behaviour, I'm fairly new to Android, but I'm generating some json (first line below) and I'm trying to send it to an application whose manifest says it accepts anything with type "application/xctsk".

The generated file is fine, but the app chooser doesn't offer that application. I can still share the file to Whatsapp and it will be fine, content-wise. However, I still can't open it from Whatsapp.
Meanwhile I can

- open the file manually
- open other files  from other sources, from Whatsapp

**Receiving app's Manifest**

```
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xctsk"
                android:host="*"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

**My code**

```
 Uri xctskURI= saveTask(somejson);
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, xctskURI);
 shareIntent.setType("application/xctsk");
 shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send to XCTrack"));
```

Comment: You can refer this https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file

Comment: I did read that several times, maybe not intelligently. Might it be as simple as the filepath not being publicized ? I'll try first thing in the morning CET

Comment: use FileProvider for uri

Comment: I AM return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.app.provider", file);

Comment: I confirm adding the file-path or external-path doesn't help, 
Also the URI has no file:// or content://, 
only /external_files/Android/data/com.example.app/files/xctsk/task.xctsk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiving app supports only `ACTION_VIEW`. You are using `ACTION_SEND`. These don't match. Either change your sending app to use `ACTION_VIEW` or change the receiving app so that it supports `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Is it as simple as that ? You'd be my hero. Indeed, the other intent filters also are on ACTION_VIEW. I'll try it as soon as I'm close to the computer and bang my head on the wall repeatedly

Comment: Not quite there yet. Now it says "No apps can perform this action."

Comment: When I skip the chooser and just startActivity(shareIntent);, app crashed and I get    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=application/xctsk (has extras) }

Comment: Then there is a problem matching your Intent to the `intent-filter` in the receiving app. I'm assuming that the "scheme" is the problem. After you construct your `Intent`, before calling `startActivity()`, print the information about the "data" in your `Intent` by calling `getData()`, `getScheme()` and `getType()`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be very strict, resolver was not satisfied with less that a perfect match.
ALL the categories had to be matched. And for some reasons, setting the MIME type erases the data.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

shareIntent.setDataAndType(xctskURI,"application/xctsk");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send to XCTrack"));
```